# realization of a syntactic parser under python

Tags: python

I am working on a python project, I have to realize a syntaxic parser complex numbers, I need to make a calculator for arithmetic operations. I want to know how to get started, can you help me please ?

Comment: take a look at ply i guess

Comment: You might find this useful: https://dbader.org/blog/writing-a-dsl-with-python?utm_content=buffer274c4&utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_campaign=buffer

Answer (score 1):

You might get away with very little if you can accept individual operands one at a time. As you may well know, Python accepts `1+2j` as a complex number, `5.36j` as an imaginary number. Thus, most parsers are overkill for parsing single complex numbers, if you ask the user to input numbers in the conventional way (ie, 10.2+i6.57). Just do a little string processing to extract the real and imaginary parts and use the `complex` function.

I suggest:

- [Tk](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/) for the GUI
- [pyparsing](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyparsing/1.5.7), if you really want a parser but it's probably unnecessary
- Python itself for doing the arithmetic

Possible exchange with user:

```
>>> x = 2+8j
>>> y = 3-7j
>>> x/y
(-0.8620689655172415+0.6551724137931035j)
>>> x*y
(62+10j)
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you help me a little more ? I don't know where to start and what the steps needed to realize this parser for complex numbers..

Comment: Nada, when you say a parser for complex numbers do you mean just a parser for individual numbers, or a parser for expressions involving complex numbers such as say 'a+ib'?

Comment: Yes I mean a parser for expressions involving complex numbers or what may be called a parser for arithmetic operations, I just want to know how to start and the steps to follow.

Comment: Much depends on how you plan to interact with the user. You need to specify that. I've edited my answer to suggest one style of interaction. If you want to be able to allow the user to define variables then perform operations on them you will be facing quite a complicated programming task.